# What is causing Google Voice upload quality to deteriorate at 30 minutes?

Tags: google-voice, upload

I use Google Voice to make and receive phone calls on my computer.  I've found that after being on the phone for 30 minutes, the other party starts to hear me as garbled, I can continue to hear them fine.  Hanging up and calling back immediately resolves the issue.

What could be the source of this issue that causes the upload for VOIP to deteriorate and my voice becomes garbled to the listener after talking for 30 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem, and it turned out to be the USB headset I was using on my Mac.  It would get further and further out of sync (audio was delayed) as the call progressed, until about 30 minutes in when my voice would be garbled for a little while and it would then get back in sync, and then repeat.  I had another USB audio device so I switched to that, which fixed it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using a USB headset too on a Mac, very suspicious!!!  Did you have to change the hardware, or just the audio driver?

Comment: I replaced only the headset.